# Query CosmosDB and return a value, if the the output value matches, send this value to CRM, if not send an email

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-cosmosdb, crm, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

**Background:**

I have built a flow that I would like to:

Query CosmosDB and return a value, if the output value matches, send this value to CRM, if not send an email.

**This is what I have done so far:**

[image]

[image]

**Does this conditional look correct for what I am doing?**

[image]

**(if the result from the query is true then, do this: send the value to CRM...., if not, send an email)**

[image]

I am not sure if the inputs are correct here.

Any guidance will be helpful.

Comment: Is the intention here to check if there are results from the query?

Comment: Query cosmos DB action will return an array. And could you please tell me how you match